# javascript execution order issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within  I have following lines written :

```
<script>

<!--
$(document).ready(function() {     // ignored ASK why?
    $('#select-native-1').change(function(){
        alert('input changed');
    });
});


<!-- google map api. -->
var map;
function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
  };
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  
    <!-- changes the map and info when option selected. -->

    $('#select-native-1').change(function(){
        if($('#select-native-1 option:selected').text() == "ok") {
        $("#ok-p").toggleClass("hide");
        $('#notok-p').toggleClass("hide");
        }else if($('#select-native-1 option:selected').text() == "notok") {
        $('#ok-p').toggleClass("hide");
        $('#notok-p').toggleClass("hide");
        }
    });     
});



</script>
```

Initially I've only had one  section containing "google map api" and the "document ready" function.

As you can see, I commented out the first document ready function as it doesn't get read by browser. ( block containing // ignored ASK why?)

Why so?

Comment: You can't have `<!-- -->` style comments inside a `<script>` tag. see: [comments section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar)

Comment: @azium http://www.javascripter.net/faq/comments.htm says you can use HTML-style comments in JS. Is it wrong?

Comment: the Code works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/t0gu74of/ What does your javascript console show when you have it uncommented?

Comment: Oh my goodness yes that's terribly wrong. That site looks like an awful resources for learning anything JavaScript. Never go back!

Comment: @azium yeah you're probably right, but it does appear to be correct on that point http://jsfiddle.net/ns3xsmyg/